# Text form that follows link

Tags: forms, input, hyperlink, submit, textfield

I have to create a form with a submit bottom following a link

```
<form action="http://domain/**(((MY TEXT INPUT VALUE)))**.htm">
<input type="text" name="verb">
<input type="submit" value="Conjugate">
</form>
```

something like this.

please note that every link should be different.

I also want that the new page be opened in a new tab/window

could you please help me, and also make changes to the form code if there is sth under newer standards. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to get the TEXTBOX value and then place it into the form action.

You can create the submit button with an onclickevent.

Or you can use jQuery

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(){
   var sTextValue = $("#MyText").val();
   $('#MyForm').attr('action', 'htttp://domain/' + sTextValue + '.htm');
   $('#MyForm').submit();
});
```

And the HTML

```
<form id="MyForm" action="">
  <input id="MyText" type="text" name="verb">
  <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Conjugate">
</form>
```

There are many ways to accomplish this. That's just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="http://domain/**(((MY TEXT INPUT VALUE)))**.htm" id="btnForm">
<input type="text" name="verb" onchange='javascript:document.getElementById("btnForm").action = "http://domain/"+ this.value +".htm"'> 
<input type="submit" value="Conjugate" >
</form
```

This would update as soon you type the text. It wouldn't require jquery. it makes use of onchange event handler of input type text

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form action="http://domain/**(((MY TEXT INPUT VALUE)))**.htm" id="btnForm">
       <input type="text" name="verb" onchange='updateFormAction(this.value)'>
       <input type="submit" value="Conjugate" >
   </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function updateFormAction(value){
          var btnForm = document.getElementById("btnForm");
          btnForm.action = "http://domain/"+ value +".htm";
    }
  </script>
```

This is more explanatory form. Its based on onchange event handler for text types.